# Refactoring with EnvDTE CodeModel on .Net 5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5, envdte, c#-code-model

I'm trying to make some refactorings in order to change namespace of some classes, create projects, etc.. using EnvDTE CodeModel.

I have tried various methods I found on the web, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using .Net 5.

For example, in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vccodemodel.vccodemodel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2019) are using directly DTE.Solution but when I try it on my solution, Intellisense gives me an error.

```
var solution = DTE.Solution;
```

Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property '_DTE.Solution'.

Another example I have found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99aa2026-bc6e-418e-9470-ee91acfcc4a4/how-to-register-vccodemodel-interface?forum=vsx) is the following:

```
var dteInstance = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
```

If I do that, the serviceProvider returns null to me. So I can't work with DTE.

I just need some help in order to get an instance of DTE, and later I would test all methods and properties that it gives me. But, how can I get the instance of DTE? How can I work with that?

I'm using an MVC web application to test it.

I appreciate so much your help.

Comment: Where are you trying your code? It seems you use it in a normal .NET 5 application. You must create a VsPackage project (VSIX) to use EnvDte. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-vspackage?view=vs-2019